# iTerm2 trigger case insensitive

Tags: regex, case-insensitive, iterm2

Recently I discovered iTerm2's wonderful feature: triggers. Now I want iTerm to highlight some pieces of text, for exampeo `error`, `fatal`, etc. I want those triggers to be case-insensitive, but I'm having a hard time setting up these triggers. According the documentation, iTerm's regular expressions are conform the ICU regular expressions rules, which [state](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Case-Insensitive-Matching) that I can use the `(?i)` flag to match case insensitive.

I tried a lot, including `(?i)/error`, `(?i)error`, etc., but none work. Please see screenshot below; any idea how to match case insensitive?

[image]

Comment: Acc. to https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html where the ICU regex flavor is mentioned as the one used in iTerm2, your `(?i)...` is bound to work. The question is off-topic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: why does a difference between documented behavior and _actual behavior_ make a question off-topic?

Comment: @iconoclast Because the current OP regex works. Anyway, it is even a dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the other two questions don't mention iTerm2.  Surely you've used regexes enough to be aware that there are different implementations in different apps & languages & utilities.  Even different things that claim to use PCRE don't always do so.

Anyway, your new claim (that it's a dupe) doesn't defend your initial claim that it's off-topic because he was experiencing undocumented behavior.  I think both of your claims are extremely questionable.

Answer (score 19):

Well, for some reason after clearing out all rules and entering the following, it all started to work :).

`(?i)error|panic|fatal`